# Cors Issue : Consume WCF Rest Service via JQuery

Tags: jquery, rest, wcf, cors

I have been following this Example

[Create and Consume WCF Restful Service Using jQuery](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/create-and-consume-wcf-restful-service-using-jquery/)

I am getting the following Error :

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:48839/EmployeeService.svc/GetEmployeeDetails/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:57402' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tushar@,

A quick google search gave me this: 
[Enabling CORS header](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/845474/Enabling-CORS-in-WCF)

For your calls to be successful, you might have to host the service and your html page on the same domain. You are having your html page from localhost on port 57402 and you are trying to access a serice at port 48839 and hence you are seeing this CORS issue.

You either have to host both service end point and the html page from the same domain and port  or you have to whitelist the access headers at the server as mentioned in the above link.

Comment: Thanks i also did the same. But I am unable to figure out where to add the header

Comment: As mentioned in the above link, Application_BeginRequest method would  be a place you could add to get this going.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Cors support via adding in your project new HttpModule.
To do so just use this code https://gist.github.com/mmorton/4113849 in your project

Answer (score 0):

Add global.asax file in your service project and

```
   protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, DELETE");

                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```